# How to generate a compilation database on macOS Catalina without turning off SIP?

Tags: macos, makefile, compilation, clang++, macos-catalina

I have tried both [Bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear) and [CompileDB](https://github.com/nickdiego/compiledb) to generate compilation database JSON from makefiles. However, it turns out that both of them generate useless empty JSON files on my mac.

`Bear` acknowledges this problem in its list of known issues.

> Security extension/modes on different operating systems might disable library preloads. In this case Bear behaves normally, but the result compilation database will be empty. (Please make sure it's not the case when reporting bugs.) Notable examples for enabled security modes are: OS X 10.11 (check with `csrutil status | grep 'System Integrity Protection'`), and Fedora, CentOS, RHEL (check with `sestatus | grep 'SELinux status'`).

Now, turning off SIP just to run one small program is not a good workaround. Do you know of any other way I can generate a compilation database from a given makefile?

Answer (score 0):

Have you investigated why compiledb failed? Under the neath, it parse the compile commands that `make` "print" out while building.

If you have the output of `make --print-directory -n`, your can also generate the json file here: https://texttoolkit.com/compilation-database-generator, it basically works like compiledb, but as a web app.